# How would I write a program that reads from a standard input and outputs only 6 characters to a line?

Tags: c++11

For example if the input was:

```
My name is Alex and
I also love coding
```

The correct output should be:

```
1:My nam  
1:e is A
1:lex an
1:d
2:I also 
2: love 
2:coding
```

So far I have this

```cpp
int  main () {
  string i;
  i.substr(0,6);
  while (getline(cin, i)) {
    cout << i << endl;
  }
}
```

Comment: I edited my question and that is what I have so far.

Comment: What seems to be the problem with this code? What is the purpose of `i.substr(0,6);` on the empty string `i` before the loop? Does it seem to print the _whole_ line when you do `cout << i << endl;`?

Comment: Yes it prints out the whole lines. It prints out my name is alex for the first line and I love coding for the second line even though I only want only 6 characters to a line like I described above. The purpose of i.substr(0,6) is that I thought it would only read upto 6 characters at a time but it does not work in my case.

Answer (score 2):

Using ranges, what you ask is almost as easy as

```cpp
    auto result = view | split('\n') | transform(chunk(6));
```

where `view` represents somehow the input, `| split('\n')` splits that input in several lines, and `| transform(chunk(6))` transforms each line by splitting it in chunks of 6 `char`s. The `result` is therefore a "range of ranges of chunks", on which you can loop with a double nested `for`.

Here's a full example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <range/v3/range/conversion.hpp>
#include <range/v3/view/chunk.hpp>
#include <range/v3/view/istream.hpp>
#include <range/v3/view/split.hpp>
#include <range/v3/view/transform.hpp>

// Comment/uncomment the line below
//#define FROM_FILE

using namespace ranges;
using namespace ranges::views;

int main() {
    // prepare a path-to-file or string buffer
#ifdef FROM_FILE
    std::string path_to_file{"/path/to/file"};
#else
    std::basic_stringbuf<char> strbuf{"My name is Alex and\nI also love coding"};
#endif

    // generate an input stream from the file or the string buffer
#ifdef FROM_FILE
    std::ifstream is(path_to_file);
#else
    std::istream is(&strbuf);
#endif

    // prevent the stream from skipping whitespaces
    is >> std::noskipws;

    // generate a range view on the stream
    ranges::istream_view<char> view(is);

    // manipulate the view
    auto out_lines = view | split('\n') // split at line breaks
                          | transform(chunk(6)); // split each in chunks of 6

    // output
    int index{};
    for (auto line : out_lines) {
        ++index;
        for (auto chunk_of_6 : line) {
            std::cout << index << ':'
                      << (chunk_of_6 | to<std::string>)
                      << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is really nice!  It feels a lot less error prone than my old-school approach.

Comment: The core part (`view | split('\n') | transform(chunk(6))` took 5 seconds to be clear in my mind. But then I spent one hour trying to remember how to prevent streams from eating whitespace. I was looking at the whole IO library. And then the memory came to mind of `std::noskipws`. I wonder if this memory will ever stick in my mind. I always spend this hour everytime, unfortunately! D:

Comment: Boring... The person who asked the question bolted from the site... Oh well, you got my vote anyway.

Answer (score 1):

First I suggest that you give your variables meaningful names. `i` isn't good for a variable you use to read lines from `std::cin`. I've changed that name to `line` in my example below.

You are on the right track with `i.substr(0,6);` but you've placed it outside of the loop where `i` is empty - and you don't print it.

You are also supposed to prepend each line with the line number but that part is completely missing.

You have also missed that you should print the next 6 characters of the read line on the next line until you've printed everything that you read.

Here's an example how that could be fixed:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    unsigned max_len = 6;

    std::string line;

    for(unsigned line_number = 1; std::getline(std::cin, line); ++line_number) {

        // loop until the read line is empty:
        while(!line.empty()) {

            // print max `max_len` characters and prepend it with the line number:
            std::cout << line_number << ':' << line.substr(0, max_len) << '\n';

            // if the line was longer than `max_len` chars, remove the first
            // `max_len` chars:

            if(line.size() > max_len) {
                line = line.substr(max_len);
            } else {                         // otherwise, make it empty
                line.clear();
            }
        }
    }
}
```